# How to modify json on server?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I have a problem in my script, where I want to change one parameter in json files, which are on some server. Changing json file works correctly, but I have no idea how to apply changes to server's json.

Here is what I already have. Make operations on `data[0]`, as `data` loads as a list.

```
import json
import urllib.request

json_name = "http://somewebsite.com/values/get.json"

with urllib.request.urlopen(json_name) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read())
    data[0]['data'] = '{"status":"done"}'
    json_id = data[0]['id']
    link_to_json = "http://somewebsite.com/values/" + str(json_id) + ".json"
    json.dump(data[0], urllib.request.urlopen(link_to_json))
```

I am given this error:

```
  File "jsontest.py", line 12, in <module>
    json.dump(data[0], urllib.request.urlopen(link_to_json))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 180, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

And don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You should be using a POST or PUT request for sending data. Why don't you use the de-facto standard library [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: @L3viathan I changed my code to way where it uses requests, but still have a problem: 
`import json
import urllib.request
import requests

payload = {"status":"done"}
json_name = "http://somewebsite.com/values/nameof.json"
r = requests.put(target_link, json = payload)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
`
It doesn't do anything in json. First print shows nothing, even if I know that there is Json at this server, and the next print shows 204 - No content.

Comment: That is a seperate problem, and here the problem very likely lies with your server, as it doesn't behave as you expect: PUTting the json data to the server is successful, and it responds with a 204, which is a successful status code.